# Why does a signed bitfield of 1 equal -1?

Tags: c, struct, bit

Can somebody provide a resource that explains everything about field bits and how they work?

```
struct byte
{
   int one :1;
}
struct byte var={1};
printf("%d",var.one);

output: -1
```

Comment: "Also, knowledege about enums and stuctures" -- You're kidding, right?

Answer (score 2):

Because in your implementation `int` is `signed int` and in signed integers the most significant bit is used as the sign bit. So a bit-field of width `1` and of type `signed int` only holds values `0` and `-1`.

Use an `unsigned int` bit-field of width `1` if you want values of either `0` or `1`.

Comment: `Because in your implementation int is signed int` Correct me if I am wrong, but `int` is by default `signed int` in all implementations.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct byte
{
   int one : 1;
   int two : 2;
};
```

Field one can store `-1`(1b) or `0`(0b)
Field two can store `-1`(11b), `-2`(10b), `+1`(01b) or `0`(00b)

---

```
struct byte
{
   unsigned int one : 1;
   unsigned int two : 2;
};
```

Field one can store `1`(1b) or `0`(0b)
Field two can store `3`(11b), `2`(10b), `1`(01b) or `0`(00b)

---

Although in both forms the bit-patterns that can be stored are same, their interpretations (assuming 2s compliment for signed) are different based on whether you are using signed or unsigned version.

**Moral**: In bitfield, almost always use unsigned type unless you have some good reason for using a signed type.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing `1` in one bit Signed int. That time the bit position is treated as sign bit as well as data bit.

So sign bit is set(`1`) means, output is negative number. So it displays `-1` as output